# jekyll - css styles are not working

Tags: html, css, jekyll, static-site

I have recently started using Jekyll.

I downloaded this theme [DentistSmile](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/dentistsmile/)

When I use jekyll build, _site is created, but it does not render css style(s). It has the css folder.

Pl find attached pic of how it looks on MY server.

[image]

I am very new to web development and don't understand much of html and css stuff. So pl help

[Here](http://ge.tt/2VWVFfU2) is the code of index.html from generated _site folder. 
FYI, I am on windows.

Comment: Could you share the HTML code for it? Check if theme you downloaded is included in HTML or not.

Comment: @pratikwebdev pl find edit. It contains a link to file

Comment: I guess that your code is working well locally and failing once on github. The idea is to provide your code repository url, in order to help you spot the problem. Certainly a `baseurl` thet is not set.

Comment: I don't understand, if you're using a theme why would you use `jekyll build` command? Shouldn't you run `jekyll serve` to see it locally? And once uploaded to GitHub Pages, you won't run any command to build the site. The other thing is, the link you posted is leading to downloading the file, so it would be better if you post the code itself, not a link to it. As a matter of fact, for your question we just need to see the `<head>` tag, where your stylesheet is linked to. Actually...  Are you really using GitHub to host the website?

Comment: don't upload the website folder you built locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not upload the _site folder, only its contents, as your CSS link is absolute.